# Cross Browser offsetWidth

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cross-browser

I've been having an issue with using offsetWidth across different browsers.  This difference in results is causing some strange layouts.  I've created a very small example that displays what I'm seeing.

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ezefiv/2/edit)

**HTML**

```
<table id="tbl">
  <tr>
    <td>Cell 1</td>
    <td>Cell 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button onclick="calc()">Calculate Offset Width</button>

<div>Cell 1 offsetWidth: <span id="c1offWidth"></span></div>
```

**js**

```
function calc(){
  document.getElementById('c1offWidth').innerHTML =
      document.getElementById('tbl').children[0].children[0].offsetWidth;
}
```

**CSS**

[Erik Meyer's Reset CSS](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

When I run this on chrome, safari, and opera the value returned for Cell 1's offset width is 72.  When I run this on firefox and IE9-10 the value returned is 77.

I was under the  impression this was the best way to calculate the width of an element including padding and border.

Is there a cross browser solution that will always return the same result?  I tried using jQuery but the results were even more confusing.

**EDIT**
Because everyone is recommending outerWidth I made a jsbin for that also.  The results still differ across browsers.  Chrome returns 36; IE9-10 and Firefox return 39.

[jsbin updated](http://jsbin.com/ezefiv/3/edit)

Comment: They ridiculousness of so many ignorant programmers using jQuery like play doh when we should be using sculpting clay! Use native JS not some resource hog library like jQuery. Do your jsperf tests!

Comment: Ah yes, the old 1 global 1 file technique. http://www.avacweb.com/17860.js. Great pattern to slow down your users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you tagged the post with jQuery, I assume that a jQuery solution is acceptable. What's wrong with [`outerWidth()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/)?

For example:

```
function calc()
{
    var the_width = $('#tbl tr:eq(0) td:eq(0)').outerWidth();
    $('#c1offWidth').html(the_width);   
}
```

Using jQuery brings a number of advantages to the table (as you can see by the reduced amount of code needed above). You should also consider using non-intrusive event handlers, too. For example, remove the `onclick` attribute from your `button`, and do this:

```
$(function() {  
    $('button').click(function() {  
        var the_width = $('#tbl tr:eq(0) td:eq(0)').outerWidth();
        $('#c1offWidth').html(the_width);  
    });
});
```

Please see the [**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/H2uGz/).

Comment: jQuery solutions are definitely accepted!  Unfortunately this demo returned 36 in Chrome but 39 in IE.  This doesn't seem to solve the problem

Comment: It returns 39px in Firefox, too. It's not a problem with the function - it is returning the correct value. The 'problem' is the way that the different browsers render the elements by default. For example, if you specify a fixed width for `#tbl`, the results are standardized > http://jsfiddle.net/H2uGz/2/

Comment: Part of the problem was that all the outerWidth and offsetWidth functions rounded the values returned.  This was mitigated by setting a width on the table as you recommended.

Comment: How about a non-JQuery answer, for curiosity's sake. I appears that you may know a way @BenM.

Answer (score 4):

The actual problem in your example was in that different browsers use different default fonts for rendering. And box-sizing for your cells is defined by content.
If you set definite width for the element (as correctly stated in one of the comment) you'll get the definite and equal result.

ps: can't post comments...

Comment: Actualy, I think this should be the accepted answer! All the other "blabla-use-jquery" answers don't tackle the problem in any way. As if jQuery would return another width - which it doesn't, of course.

Answer (score 3):

`offsetWidth` is not reliable cross-browser. I would recommend using jQuery's [`outerWidth()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/) instead.

```
$("#your-element").outerWidth();
```

See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tNhqv/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's [`.outerWidth()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/) if you need to get a cross-browser calculated width including things like borders and margin.